# Excel help - IF data in specific range of cells, THEN return column titles in same cell

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have a table with several week ending dates at the top of each column. I want to search a row for any column with data in and then return, in a list, all the column titles that had data in.

I have attached a picture to better show what I mean, in the picture I have simply typed the dates in. I would like a formula, maybe VBA? that can do this for me but its proving more difficult than I thought.

[What final result should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdVG2.png)

Really appreciate any help!
Thanks

** edit: I have found a formula which works but will be incredibly long. Surely there is a way to combine and shorten?

=IF(C5<>0,TEXT(C1,"dd/mm")&" | ","")&IF(D5<>0,TEXT(D1,"dd/mm")&" | ","")&IF(E5<>0,TEXT(E1,"dd/mm"),"")

The above code only works in 3 columns too... Not the required 60 plus!

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code into a module, and in cell B2 type `=IFERROR(getNonBlankCells($C$1:$K$1,C2:K2),"")` and drag it down to B5.

```
Function getNonBlankCells(Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, n As Integer, test As String
    Dim A As Variant, B As Variant, ret(), newret(), t As Integer, p As Integer
    n = Rng1.Columns.Count
    ReDim ret(1 To n, 0)
    A = Rng1.Value2
    B = Rng2.Value2
    i = 1
    For j = 1 To n
        If B(1, j) <> "" Then
            ret(i, 0) = A(1, j)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next j
    ReDim newret(LBound(ret) To UBound(ret))
    For t = LBound(ret) To UBound(ret)
        If ret(t, 0) <> "" Then
            p = p + 1
            newret(p) = ret(t, 0)
        End If
    Next t
    ReDim Preserve newret(LBound(newret) To p)
    getNonBlankCells = Join(newret, ", ")
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very close! It only returns the dates as the excel number associated though; not in dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: I figured that you had them stored as text or as general, because the formatting of them were different, some dates used "-" vs "/". If you change those columns to general, you should be good.

Comment: Ah sadly not, because I enter a few dates then drag across to fill in as many boxes as I need, it always seems to automatically make it a number. It keeps giving a list like this: 43490, 43504, 43525